# Include path problem when compiling wxWidgets app

Tags: makefile, include, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I'm now compiling wxWidgets' hello world sample: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html
using MingGW-w64 and it's mingw32-make on windows, and I'm using the pre-compiled Windows binaries it provides.

I have already compile successfully using

```
g++ -o hello -I/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll/mswu -I/d/local/wxWidgets/include -L/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll hello.cpp -lwxbase31u -lwxmsw31u_core
```

(I run this git-bash), and it can be execute normally too.

But when I copy the same line into makefile like this:

```
all: hello
hello: hello.cpp
    g++ -o hello -I/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll/mswu -I/d/local/wxWidgets/include -L/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll hello.cpp -lwxbase31u -lwxmsw31u_core
```

and run with mingw32-make.exe in terminal, this error happened:

```
hello.cpp:3:10: fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:3: hello] Error 1
```

I'm not sure if it's the including path problem, because It actually compile successfully when I run the same line in terminal directlty.

Comment: where is the makefile located?

Comment: @Igor same as hello.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using the "git bash" terminal when you try with your Makefile ?

Regards
Xav'

Answer (score 0):

After trying executing in cmd and git-bash a few times. I found it's probably the path style problem. I tried 2 cases of path specification below:

First:

```
g++ -o hello -I/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll/mswu -I/d/local/wxWidgets/include -L/d/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll hello.cpp -lwxbase31u -lwxmsw31u_core
```

Second:

```
g++ -o hello -ID:\local\wxWidgets\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu -ID:\local\wxWidgets\include -LD:\local\wxWidgets\lib\gcc810_x64_dll hello.cpp -lwxbase31u -lwxmsw31u_core
```

Git-bash(execute in terminal directly): only **first** case successfully compiled.

Git-bash(using mingw32-make): only **second** case successfully compiled.

cmd(execute in terminal directly): only **second** case successfully compiled.

cmd(using mingw32-make): only **second** case successfully compiled.

Conclusion: I think mingw32-make using "traditional" Windows path style (backslash), even under git-bash.

**Update**:

I found that mingw32-make also support forword slash, so I can rewrite as:

```
g++ -o hello -ID:/local/wxWidgets/lib/gcc810_x64_dll/mswu ...
```

So I think it's better to use relative path in makefile, to prevent that (**D:**) in path, and also more portable(unix/linux use backslash too).

Comment: yes, most of Makefile's do use the relative path. Just look at the minimal sample makefile. Or any other makefile for that matter.